# Get an object from a MVC model in JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `DropDownListFor` which holds keys from a `Dictionary` in a class which my MVC Model holds. When I select an item in that list, I would like to then set the text of a `TextArea` to that corresponding value in the dictionary. To accomplish this, I am trying to use JQuery.

**My Issue**

It doesn't seem like I can get my dictionary. To get it, I would have to make a call like this:

```
var fiConfigValues = $('#IdentifiFIConfiguration.Config.Configuration');
```

Where `IdentifiFIConfiguration` is the `model` in my ASP.NET MVC View, the `Config` is a class and the `Configuration` is the dictionary I am trying to reference.

However, it seems that code does not run, and I also don't know how to convert that `var` into a `Dictionary` so I can access the key/value pairs.

**My Question**

In JQuery, (or even in Razor if there is a way!), how can I access my dictionary that is nested within a couple of classes inside my `Model` so that I can change the value of my `TextArea`?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. It's just a dictionary with string values as the keys and values.

Comment: Can you - Yes. Should you - No. Better to handle the change event of your dropdownlist and use ajax to pass the selected value to a controller method that looks up the value and returns it, then update the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively wanting to do view/model binding on the client side. Usually one could leverage a framework like KnockOut.JS and KnockOut.Mappings to assist with creating the client models and binding to those.

However, if you can't go with that or don't want to mess with it, you can manually do things with JQuery and JS. This may be over kill, but I tend to lean towards more structure and clarity. One solution could be to iterate over your server side model and generate its client side counterpart. Then, set up a change event via Jquery and locate the corresponding client model in a collection based on a selected value. Once found, update the text area with the model's value. Code follows...

View Code (with client script):

```
    @model SoPOC.Models.IdentifiFIConfigurationViewModel

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedConfigId,
                            new SelectList(Model.Config.ConfigurationList, "Key", "Key", Model.SelectedConfigId),
                            "Select a Config"
                            )

    <textarea id="configDescription" rows="10"></textarea>

    @section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //array to hold your client side models
            ConfigItemList = []

            //definition method to query your array
            ConfigItemList.GetItem = function (condition) {
                for (i = 0, L = this.length; i < L; i++) {
                    with (this[i]) {
                        if (eval(condition)) { return this[i]; }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Your client side item model
            ConfigItem = function (key, value) {
                var self = this;
                self.Key = key;
                self.Value = value;
            }

            //function to update views with model data
            function UpdateView(configItem) {
                console.log(configItem);
                $("#configDescription").val(configItem.Value);
            }

            //Your C# code to loop over your dictionary and create the client side version
            @if(Model.Config.ConfigurationList.Any())
            {
                foreach(var item in Model.Config.ConfigurationList)
                {
                    //We are mixing C# and JS code here
                    @:ConfigItemList.push(new ConfigItem(@item.Key, '@item.Value'));
                }
            }

            $(function () {
             //bind change event to drop down to update view with model data
                $("#SelectedConfigId").change(function () {
                    UpdateView(ConfigItemList.GetItem("Key === "+  $(this).val()));
                });

                console.log(ConfigItemList.length);
                console.log(ConfigItemList);
            });
        </script>
    }
```

The important parts are the server side iterations over your Dictionary object generating client side models to store into a client side array. After that, you have all the data in a usable structure you can query for. I left the debug output in to help you troubleshoot if needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

var fiConfigValues = $('@Model.Config.Configuration');

Comment: And then how would I access the key/value pairs?

Comment: I could affirm if you had post your model class, but I believe you'll access your key value pair using the code above.

Comment: The dictionary is on the MVC model server side. What you have above will evaluate the `@...` to the class name and then Jquery will be unable to find anything with that as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could do this

```
var fiConfigValues = $('@IdentifiFIConfiguration.Config.Configuration');
```

i think fiConfigValues become a array in javascript not sure not a expert someone might give the right answer.

than you iterate

```
for(var key in fiConfigValues){
  var value = array[key];
  console.log(value);
}
```

that just my guessing